# Fast calculations using fast-Fourier convolution

Tags: time-complexity, arrays, python, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Consider an array $X$ with shape $H \times W$. Let $Y$ be the other array of the same shape and $Z$ is an array of shape $h \times w$.

We want to construct an array $R$ of shape $(H-h + 1, W-w+ 1)$ by the following rule:

$$\displaystyle R[k, l] = \sum_{i, j} (X[i,j] -  Y[i,j])^2 +$$
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{h-1}\sum_{j=0}^{w-1}[(X[k + i, l + j] - Z[i, j])^2 - (X[k + i, l + j] -  Y[k + i, l + j])^2]$$

So it's better to represent it via the image: we erase some subarray of size $h \times w$ in $X - Y$, change it by $X_{h, w} - Z$ and compute the sum of squares.

Using dynamic programming we can solve it pretty fast, but it's still a time-consuming process. I think that it's possible to calculate such an array using fast Fourier convolutions. But we need to determine convolution arrays to do that.

Any hints?